# Dagger Hilt how to inject classes into ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I recently started using DI in my project through Dagger Hilt. I'm having no problems when injecting instances into Activities, fragments... etc. But I am not sure how to inject a class instance into ViewModel.

My approach at the moment consists of adding the classes I need to the constructor of the viewmodel as such:

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
application: Application,
@Named("classA") var classA: ClassA,
@Named("classB") var classB: ClassB
) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

and then in my AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("ClassA")
fun provideClassA(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = ClassA(context)

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("ClassB")
fun provideClassB(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = ClassB(context)

}
```

Which works great, but ideally and in the case I wanted to add many more instances of other classes, I would prefer doing

```
@Inject
lateinit var classA:ClassA
```

But I presume this is not possible, as adding @AndroidEntryPoint to the viewModel is not possible, so how are classes injected into viewmodel? or do we just add them to constructor, as in my current solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add them to the constructor. And in your case, you don't even need `@Named()` because both of you dependencies provide another class. So:

```
class YourViewModel @ViewModelInject(
   @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
   private val classA: ClassA, // or non-private, but it has to be a val
   private val classB: ClassB // or non-private, but it has to be a val
) : ViewModel()
```

Furthermore, you don't need to use AndroidViewModel here. Dagger will provide you the application context via `@ApplicationContext private val context: Context`. Be aware that in order to use this viewmodel, the fragment and activity has to be annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`

Comment: This gave the warning `This field leaks a context object` for context

Comment: @AbhishekAN set leak-reason to null inside onDestroy() method to avoid leaks